# Clarification on definition of a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

Quick question; lets say that $S$ is a basis of $V$. I understand that this means all vectors in $S$ are linearly independent, and that every vector in $V$ is an element of $\text{span} \ S$.

Is it also required that every element of $\text{span} \ S$ is an element of $V$?

I've been getting different answers from different sources so I'm a bit confused.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Yes, of course: the very first condition is that $\;S\subset V\;$

Comment: yes span of S = V

Answer (score 0):

$S$ is a familly of elements of $V$, so its span **is** in $V$.

Comment: (since $V$ is closed under addition and multiplication by scalars.)